# Occasional error opening .accdb database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have some code that does an `UPDATE` query in an Access database. Sometimes it works, sometimes I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot open database ''.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.
```

Here's the code:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));   //read as ANSI encoding

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=c:\\myDatabase.accdb");
con.Open();

for (int i = 2; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)  //ignore the first 2 lines
{
    string line = lines[i];         //get the current line

    string[] values = line.Split('\t');     //split line at the tabs

    using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [myTable](" +
        "[Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], " +
   "[Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1], [Field1]" +
   "[Field1], [Field1], [Field1]" +
   ") VALUES (" +
   "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?" +
   ")", con))
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 23; y++)
   {
       if (values[y] != "")
       {
           com.Parameters.Add("@p" + y + "", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = (object)values[y] ?? DBNull.Value;
       }
       else
       {
           com.Parameters.Add("@p" + y + "", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = DBNull.Value;
       }
        }     
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
con.Close();
```

Any idea what is causing this? Why it only works some of the time? I do not have the actual .accdb file open in Access while I'm running the code.

Thanks!

EDIT: Prior to running the above code, it runs this code just fine:

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=c:\\myDatabase.accdb");
        con.Open();

        string strCreate = "CREATE TABLE [myTable](" +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +            
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +          
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +             
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255), " +
                            "[Field1] Text(255))";              

        OleDbCommand cCom = new OleDbCommand(strCreate, con);
        cCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cCom.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: it fails at `com.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you catch the exception and inner exception? It should shed some light on the issue:

```
    try
    {
        // Your Code Here
    }
    catch (OleDbException e)
    {
        Messagebox.Show(e.InnerException.Message);
    }
```

Comment: this gives me an error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myApp.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @JeffBrady what about just the e.Message instead of e.InnerException.Message?

Comment: @JeffBrady also, what's the file size on your Access database?

Comment: it just gives the same error: `Cannot open database ''.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.`

Comment: @JeffBrady that's what I was afraid of, JET used to have limitations at 2 GB.  If your insert is breaking that threshold, that might be the culprit.  You might consider doing a migration over to a SQL database if that's feasible (you can house your data there and just have reference tables in Access that link to SQL - no change from a user's perspective).

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL isn't an option at this point. I'll look into getting rid of some stuff in the database to slim it down. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks like the solution. I was able to get rid of some stuff and got the DB down to 1.5GB, and haven't seen the error since. Thanks @wilso132!